# Blur effect not working with all elements in Tailwind CSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I`m trying to make blurry, sticky navbar. It works great when scrolling over elements like images, but when scrolling over text it is not working. Here is my full code:

https://play.tailwindcss.com/GaBOgqZIsq

Comment: Reduce the blur level from **20px** to **5px**, it should work fine after that.

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine for me. Here's a sandbox with your working code :

https://play.tailwindcss.com/pPuNJlPjHi

I edited a little your bg-class and put down your opacity so you can see the blurry effect.
In my opinion it seems that your problem is more a question of **contrast** than you effect not working

Comment: it works on this sandbox but when i use it in my code it is not woking

Comment: you can see full code here https://play.tailwindcss.com/GaBOgqZIsq

Comment: Definitely works for me in the sandbox you sent me... Tried your code in one of my angular projects which uses Tailwind and it works perfectly fine

Comment: weird, what do you think the proplrm is?

Comment: Like that I wouldn’t know. Can you put your code live on a server or share it on GitHub somehow ?

Comment: I tried run the sandbox on my phone and it works perfectly so it looks like the problem is in my computer i also tries change the browser to edge but it still not working

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's your version, in my case I put "filter blur-sm" and it worked perfectly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).